# "Buffering" data entry into online form in case of disconnection (Racket)

Tags: mysql, sql, http, web, racket

My company has an existing framework for online medical data entry. We are now working with some doctors in China who are interested in using this framework, however they have some concerns.

On the technical side, the online data entry forms are written in Racket and saved into a MySQL database on a server in Europe after entry. Their concerns are that in some hospitals, Internet connection might be unstable and thus doctors might lose data that was just entered into a form.

So the question is, is there some possibility to somehow buffer the data offline on the respective doctor's workstation before attempting a save to the MySQL database, in order to reduce the risk of data loss. My first instinct was to answer no, because whatever measures the application might take, it's still a web application, so when the Internet connection breaks, there won't be any possibility on the application side to save the data.

Am I right with my guess or might there be a way of accomplishing this? Another idea was creating a completely new application used for data entry and just send the data to the database when data entry is complete; this is however not feasible for the scope of this project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a local MySQL database, make all the data from the forms be inserted into this database an then when you're sure you have internet connection you export this data to the remote MySQL database, from a different GUI preferably.

Take a look at this page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html and check if it helps.

Comment: The problem is that all this would have to be done on the doctor's side, not on mine/our company's. So unless I'd whip up a really simple GUI for dumping the local MySQL DB to our server, it'd not be a feasible option - but thanks, I will take a look at that!

Comment: Yeah, I understand what are you saying, you need a simple interface so the client can use it without any difficulty. I know how hard is to listen to clients complains, lol. Anyway, this is just an initial idea, put some effort on it and come back bringing the results you found. Maybe `mysqldump` isn't the best way to synchronize your data, but I don't see other way than to make a local database and then push it to the remote.

Comment: If you find any technical difficulty people here will be happy to help you, just make sure to ask a new question pointing exactly what your difficulty is, but first make a little research on that.