# Auto-save form data to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, racket, autosave

The application I'm currently working on is a way for doctors to enter patient parameters into a Web UI. There are certain forms with data associated to them, and each day should only have one form. Our problem at the moment is as follows:

There's a lot of patient data to enter into each respective form, and doctors are worried that after entering all data and hitting the Submit button at the end of the page, which updates the MySQL database, their Internet connection might break and they will have to re-enter all their data. This will quickly lead to frustration.

How can I achieve preventing this problem? My first thought was of a kind of auto-save feature, that periodically updates the MySQL database with the data that was already entered into the current page's forms, without the user having to hit Submit first. Unfortunately, I don't know how to approach this problem. Any ideas? The application is written in Racket, but the forms are plain old simple HTML and a MySQL server at the backend.

Comment: You will need to implement an AJAX interface to your HTML pages. You can manually implement one or use a front-end framework or library.  Basically you'll have your HTML/JavaScript layer speak to a dedicated endpoint on you Racket layer.

Comment: Interesting. I have also read a lot about using jQuery to maybe solve this problem. Would I "just" have to include the jquery.js on my page and write a script for the auto-save maybe?

Comment: jQuery has an ajax adapter that will work, yes.

Comment: you can store this data to local storage , then every time the connection is correct, send it to the server.
this link may help you:http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/05/sisyphus-js-client-side-drafts-and-more/

Comment: In case anyone finds the link useful this appears to be a follow-up question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457117/buffering-data-entry-into-online-form-in-case-of-disconnection-racket